# Why is Animation Tween always running from 0.0 to 1.0?

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-web

I want to make an animation in flutter using

```
  late AnimationController controller1;
  late Animation<double> animation1;

  @override
  void initState() {
   super.initState();

   controller1 = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
      vsync: this,
    );
    animation1 = Tween(begin: 50.0, end: 0.0).animate(controller1)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });

    controller1.forward();
}
```

No matter which values I put in as "begin" and "end" - the

`controller1.value`

always goes from 0.0 to 1.0. What is my mistake here?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to get `animation1.value`, not `controller1.value` - for more info refer to [Animations tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/tutorial) (and in particular [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/tutorial#tween))

Comment: AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
    vsync: this,
  )..repeat(reverse: true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the `animation1.value`, not the <del>controller1.value</del> and you can verify it using the following code :) :

```
 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  controller =
      AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 2), vsync: this);

  animation = Tween<double>(begin: 50.0, end: 0.0).animate(controller)
    ..addListener(() {
      // #enddocregion addListener
      setState(() {
        print("Animation value: ${animation.value}");

        //TODO: you can uncomment this print to see the value of the controller
        //print("Controller value: ${controller.value}");
      });
    });
  controller.forward();
}
```

[image: Console logs]

Check out the official tutorial for more info :)

[Animations tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/tutorial)

By the way, since `controller.value` goes from 0.0 to 1.0, you can consider it as a sort of completion percentage :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `animation1.value` instead of controller value.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
    );
    animation = Tween<double>(begin:50, end:0.0).animate(controller);
    animation.addListener((){
      print(animation.value);
    });
    controller.forward();
  }
```

Output

> 50 50
> 41.285714285714285
> 36.714285714285715
> 31.57142857142857
> 24.857142857142854
> 20.14285714285714
> 15.428571428571423
> 10.428571428571423
> 5.714285714285708
> 0.9999999999999929 0

[Code example](https://github.com/flutter/website/blob/main/examples/animation/animate1/lib/main.dart)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort this using `SlideTransition` and `FadeTransition`.
I guess we should only use `Transition` widgets for... transitions? while things like `Positioned` and `Opacity` are for more static widgets? Not sure...

What it looks like: https://youtu.be/hj7PkjXrgfg

Anyways, here's the replacement code, if anyone's looking for reference:

```
class WeatherCloudWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final double sunSize;
  final CloudProperties properties;

  WeatherCloudWidget({Key key, this.properties, this.sunSize})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _WeatherCloudWidget();
}

class _WeatherCloudWidget extends State<WeatherCloudWidget>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation<Offset> position;
  Animation<double> opacity;

  final alphaTween = new Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0);

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _startAnimation();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // screen width and height
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    final properties = widget.properties;

    var vertical = (screenHeight * 0.5) +
        (widget.sunSize * properties.verticalOffset * -1);

    var horizontal =
        (screenWidth * 0.5) + (widget.sunSize * properties.tweenEnd);

    return Positioned(
      left: horizontal,
      top: vertical,
      child: SlideTransition(
          position: position,
          child: FadeTransition(
            opacity: opacity,
            child: Image.asset(
              properties.path,
              width: properties.getScaledWidth(widget.sunSize),
              height: properties.getScaledHeight(widget.sunSize),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _startAnimation() {
    controller = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), vsync: this);

    position = new Tween<Offset>(
      begin: new Offset(widget.properties.tweenStart, 0.0),
      end: new Offset(0.0, 0.0),
    ).animate(new CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.decelerate));

    opacity = alphaTween.animate(controller);

    controller.forward();
  }
}
```